# How to read lines in a file, multiply them and put them to another file?

Tags: python

I would like to improve the code below by READING the lines in integers.text and then multiply them.

The products must be added to products.txt. I tried this code:

```
f = open("integers.txt", "r")

def mult(a, b=1, c=1, d=1, e=1, f=1, g=1):

  d = a*b*c*d*e*f*g

  return d

print(mult(1, 2, 3))

print(mult(2,3))

print(mult(1,2,3,4,5))

print(mult(1,3,2,5,6,7,7))

print(mult(1))

f = open("products.txt", "w")

f.write("6\n")

f.write("6\n")

f.write("120\n")

f.write("8820\n")

f.write("1\n")

f.close()
```

The file named integers.txt has 5 lines with:

```
1,2,3
2,3
1,2,3,4,5
1,3,2,5,6,7,7
1
```

The products of each lines should be put in another file named products.txt

Comment: Have you tried searching for "read a file in python" ?

Comment: What problem are you having? Read each line, call `split()` to split it into a list, and call `int()` to convert each list element to a number. Then call `mult(*list_of_numbers)`

Answer (score 0):

For each line of the input file

- split the line in a list
- convert each item to an `int`
- call `multiply` with them
- store the result in the output file

```
def mult(a, b=1, c=1, d=1, e=1, f=1, g=1):
    return a * b * c * d * e * f * g

with open("integers.txt", "r") as fin, \
        open("products.txt", "w") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        values = list(map(int, line.rstrip().split(",")))
        fout.write(f"{mult(*values)}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce function in python to multiply a list of numbers. This way you wont need to write a function for multiplication with 6 or more arguments:

```
with open("integers.txt", "r") as inp:
    with open("products.txt", "w") as outfile:
        for line in inp:
            vals = list(map(lambda x: int(x.strip()), line.split(',')))
            result = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, vals)
            outfile.write(f"{result}\n")
```